# How do I use Javascript to create txt file and also create a html file with the content of the txt file?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, promise, text-files

How do I use Javascript to create a text.txt file and also create an HTML file with the content of the text file?

1. How do I make sure that I have a valid HTML5 compliant containing doctype, head with title, body file which contains an HTML table displaying the same content as the text.txt file?
2. Should I use Promise.all to make sure that my program do not wait for the processing of the text.txt file to complete before moving on to creating an HTML file?

Comment: Can you show what your text file contains?

Comment: lunch,bento box b - sashimi,box combo,   $9.59
dinner,vegetable sushi,6 rolls,     $3.50
dinner,tuna roll,3 rolls,     $4.50
dinner,roe,2 rolls,    $3.95
lunch,bento box a - chicken teriyaki,box combo,$8.59                     
                                                                                                I  use fs.append to get these into my txt file